# Need Best database to process huge data

Tags: php, mongodb, elasticsearch, bigdata, database

I have situation as below.

Every day I am getting 256 GB products information from different online shops and content providers (Ex. CNET datasource). 
These information can be CSV, XML and TXT files. Files will be parsed and storing into MongoDB. 
Later information will be transformed to searchable and indexed into Elasticsearch.

All 256 GB information is not different every day. Mostly 70% information will be same and few fields like Price, Size, Name and etc will be changed frequently. 
I am processing Files usig PHP.

My problem are

1. Parsing huge data
2. Mapping the fields inside DB ( ex. title is not title for all onlineshops. They will give field name as Short-Title or some other name)
3. Increasing GB of information every day. How to store all and process. ( may be Bigdata but not sure how to use it)
4. Searching information fast with huge data.

Please suggest me suitable Database for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. parsing huge data - Spark is fastest distributed solution for your need, thought you have 70% same data just for comparing its duplicate you anyway have to process it, here you can do mapping n all as well.
2. data store, if you are doing any aggregation here, i would recommend to use HBase/Impala , if each row of product is important to you use cassandra
3. For serching nothing is faster than lucene, so use use Solr or Elasticsearch whatever you think comfortable, both are good.

Comment: thank you Amey... i am exploring possibilities